# Kotlin named constructors

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following code in **Dart** programming language

```
class HttpResponse {
  final int code;
  final String? error;

  HttpResponse.ok() : code = 200; <== This functionality 
  HttpResponse.notFound()         <== This functionality
      : code = 404,
        error = 'Not found';

  String toString() {
    if (code == 200) return 'OK';
    return 'ERROR $code ${error.toUpperCase()}';
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this in Kotlin, I know that I can use static methods, however static methods don't have the purpose of initializing a class, is there a way where this can be achieved in Kotlin?

Comment: Kotlin (and Java) do not have named constructors. You're probably looking for static factory methods.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking or [companion objects](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/objects-and-companion-objects.html#companion-objects) - they will give you static functions and look like your example.

Comment: The easiest 1:1 translation for your code is probably companion objects. For your specific example enum class would do that just fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for [Sealed Classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html).

```kotlin
sealed class HttpResponse(val code: Int, val error: String? = null) {
    
    class Ok(code: Int) : HttpResponse(code)
    
    class NotFound(code: Int, error: String?) : HttpResponse(code, error)
    
    override fun toString(): String {
        return if (code == 200) "OK"
        else "ERROR $code ${error?.toUpperCase()}"
    }
}

fun main() {
    val okResponse = HttpResponse.Ok(200)
    val notFoundResponse = HttpResponse.NotFound(404, "Not found")
}
```

Comment: Can I prevent initialization from the ```HttpResponse``` class in order to maintain the same functionality as the original code from Dart?

Comment: Sealed classes cannot be instantiated by default. Trying to create `HttpResponse(100, "Test")` throws an error.

Comment: But this allows something like `HttpResponse.Ok(404)` or `HttpResponse.NotFound(200, "ok")` which Dart code doesn't.

Comment: I don't know Dart :( do you want to just call `Ok(200)` without the `HttpResponse` prefix? Then just move the `class Ok` outside of the body of `HttpResponse`, just put them in the same file but without nesting them.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that `sealed class` is the preferred way but there is another option of making the constructor private and accessing it via factory methods in `companion object`. That way you can achieve "named constructors".

```
data class HttpResponse private constructor(
    private val code: Int,
    private val error: String? = null,
) {
    companion object {
        fun ok() = HttpResponse(200)
        fun notFound() = HttpResponse(404, "Not found")
    }
}

fun main() {
    val responseOk = HttpResponse.ok()
    val responseNotFound = HttpResponse.notFound()
}
```

Comment: This is the closest answer to the original code since it has no private constructor.

Answer (score 2):

[Sealed Classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html) is the way to go:

```
import java.util.Locale.US

sealed class HttpResponse(val code: Int, val error: String?) {
  object Ok : HttpResponse(200, null)
  object NotFound : HttpResponse(404, "Not found")

  override fun toString() = when (this) {
    Ok -> "OK"
    NotFound -> "ERROR $code ${error?.uppercase(US)}"
  }
}

fun main() {
  println(HttpResponse.Ok) // OK
  println(HttpResponse.NotFound) // ERROR 404 NOT FOUND
}
```

*Since I cannot suggest an edit or post a comment, I am adding my modified version of zOqvxf's answer here.*

If you keep your superclass parameters unexposed in this way, there is no worry for usage like `HttpResponse.Ok(404)` as mentioned in the comment.